# setup views for installation in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on iphone application. I want to make an app that will have some setup views which will appear only on installation and not after the app is installed. How could i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have things that appear when the app is first *launched*, but you can’t do anything at *installation* time per se. What you want to do is something like this in your application delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    static NSString *firstLaunchKey = @"HasLaunchedBefore";

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:firstLaunchKey] == YES) {
        // Launch your application as you normally do
    } else {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:firstLaunchKey];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        // Show your first-launch views here.
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NSUserDefaults API to keep a record of the fact the app has been run on the device.

When deciding which views to show, use a check like this:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasAppLaunchedBefore"])
{
    // this isn't the first time the app has run
    // show normal views
}
else
{
    // this is the first time the app has run
    // show first-time views

    [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasAppLaunchedBefore"];
}
```